# Function parameters of the form foo(A | B | C)

Tags: php, c++, algorithm, function

This is a language-independent question, though I've tagged with languages just to give some tags relevant to the code samples I'm posting below. I'm somewhat new to programming. In various languages I've seen functions that have parameters separated by what I think is the bitwise `OR` operator. I've used these functions without understanding exactly how the parameters work.

I'll give some examples in case you're not sure what I'm talking about.

From http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php:

```
<?php

// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);

// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// Reporting E_NOTICE can be good too (to report uninitialized
// variables or catch variable name misspellings ...)
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);

// Report all errors except E_NOTICE
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Report all PHP errors (see changelog)
error_reporting(E_ALL);

// Report all PHP errors
error_reporting(-1);

// Same as error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

?>
```

From http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/:

```
ofstream myfile ("example.bin", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);
```

What exactly is the deal with functions that take parameters like that? Can someone explain?

Comment: it's a bitmask. Each flag is a power of two, so they can be ORed together without losing any info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you lookup what those constants are, you'll see they'll be like this: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, etc.

So by adding them all together basically, (what the bitwise does AFAIK from this: "Bit shifting in PHP is arithmetic.") you get a new "number".

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

The manual page has a lot of good info on how it works.

So basically to answer the question of how that function works, it is accepting one integer, and the bitwise operator is doing the "math" and turning those three constants into one new number.

```
var_dump(E_ERROR);
var_dump(E_WARNING);
var_dump(E_PARSE);
var_dump(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

int(1)
int(2)
int(4)
int(7)
```

So it's the same as:

```
error_reporting(7);
```

Comment: Was going to answer but just added to this already good answer.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing as `a + b + c`.  It's just an expression, with
the `|` (bitwise or) operator.

Comment: Comparison between addition and bitwise or is a bit dangerous for a new programmer without explaining the difference. "E_ERROR + E_WARNING" seems to work (and sounds more logical in most cases..) - until someone tries to apply it to "E_ERROR + E_ERRORORWARNING" yielding a carry bit.

Comment: @MikkoRantanen At which point, I should explain _all_ of the C++ operators, and their precedence?

Comment: Or you could use "a - b - c" as an example, if your goal was to compare expressions. From your answer I couldn't tell whether you used "a + b + c" as an alternative to "a | b | c", which would be horrible form. In most cases with bitmasks "a + b + c" and "a | b | c" yield the same result - that is until two values have overlapping bits set.

Comment: @MikkoRantanen Ouch.  My intend was just to say that an expression is an expression.  My impression was that the OP didn't know that `|` was an operator.  I would definition argue for the `|` in this case, since that is what is actually wanted.  (And as you say, if `a` and `b` happen to be identical, `+` will give wrong results.)

Answer (score 0):

These are [predefined constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php), whose values are combined to produce a bit field.

You can use `decbin()` in PHP to give an insight into how these constants work. `decbin` produces a string which shows the binary representation of the number.

```
printf("%02s", decbin(E_ERROR));                // output 01
printf("%02s", decbin(E_WARNING));              // output 10
printf("%02s", decbin(E_ERROR | E_WARNING));    // output 11
```

(I padded all the values so that the `OR` operation is clear)

You're passing a single number to the function, whose value represents the options you want to enable. In the function, the options could be extracted using bitwise `&`:

```
function func($flag) {
    if ($flag & E_ERROR) echo "E_ERROR enabled";
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score -1):

These are flags. Sometimes a function receives multiple indications on how to operate, such as whether to open the file in binary mode, or in read-only mode, etc... This modes are not mutually exclusive - file can be opened for reading in both text and binary mode, or for writing in both text and binary mode. So you need to be able to specify both options together if you want.

One simple way to achieve this is with bit flags. You have one integer number that holds all the flags. The least significant bit says, for example, if the file is to be opened in text mode (0 - text, 1 - binary), the second bit from the right says whether to open for read or write, etc...

To implement this you use constants:

```
BINARY = 1
WRITE = 2
```

Now, if you want to open in both binary and write mode, you use `BINARY | WRITE` - which results in 3.

The called function then breaks the number back into bits:

```
isBinary = (flags & BINARY) != 0;
isWriteMode = (flags % WRITE) != 0;
```

Answer (score -4):

I think

```
// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

is equivalent to the following in C or C++

```
// Report simple running errors
int const error_filter = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE;
error_reporting( error_filter );
```

Most probably, the symbols E_ERROR, E_WARNING are numbers with a single bit set, such as for example

```
E_ERROR     = 00000001
E_WARNING   = 00000010
E_PARSE     = 00000100
```

So, a bitwise-OR of them returns a number with the bit set in all of those positions

```
error_filter = E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE = 00000111
```

One tricky thing is the type of `error_filter`, I wrote `int` but that may not be pedantically correct. One can say `uint32_t`. Another alternative is to leave the type altogether as in the original code.

Comment: Can the downvoters kindly point out the mistake in the answer? That would be a help and a learning exercise.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but they were probably before the edits.  Also, comparison with c or c++ probably doesn't help someone who would ask this question and php.net shows what ints these constants define.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Hmmm, uh, the question was tagged as "C++" too. The answer, even before the edit, is not specific to the values of those consts, but the fact that it the (real/final) function parameter is a bitwise-OR of the individual constants.

Comment: Just guessing, as I said I didn't downvote it because it was not wrong.